# Div Blocks under each other in mobile version

Tags: html, css, responsive

There are 3 block different size in a row. How can I make them responsive, because in mobile version they overlay at each other.

```css
.watch {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 224px;
    height: 69px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #918A83;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.watch-elements {
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

.watch p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.mouse {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #DAD3CC;
    width: 577px;
    height: 69px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.mouse-elements {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.mouse p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

.chat-bot {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #09A753;
    border-radius: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 227px;
    height: 39px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chat-bot img {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.chat-bot p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15px;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .watch img {
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        left: 0;
    }
    .watch p {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h2 class="header-text">Practical business advice and knowhow<br>customized to your needs</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="watch">
      <div class="watch-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/icon2.svg">
        <p>Watch Presenation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="mouse">
      <div class="mouse-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/Icon1.svg"><br>
        <p>Scroll Down</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-right">
    <div class="chat-bot">
      <img src="assets/img/06w.png">
      <p>Hi, can I help you?</p>
      <img src="assets/img/icons/icon3.svg" style="float: right; margin-right: -60px; margin-top: -39px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, they arrange in a row as on image

[image: screenshot]

In mobile version left block disappears and I can not see it, also second and third block overlay at each other.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices please try position: relative instead of position: absolute. Don't forget to adjust other CSS values as per your requirements. Hope this will solve your issues

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
.watch, .mouse, .chat-bot{
position:relative;
right:auto;
left:auto;
top:auto;
bottom:auto;
margin:5px 0
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it helped me. and how can I take down them at the bottom of section?

Comment: @Rajecsh after that I will be able to note your answer as a correct

Comment: you can try this
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
.watch, .mouse, .chat-bot{
position:relative;
right:auto;
left:auto;
top:auto;
bottom:auto;
margin:5px 0;
width:auto;
}
.d-flex{
  flex-direction:column;
  width:100%
}
}

Comment: it did not help me( on iphone5 I still can not see them. Maybe I need to use all screens media query?

Answer (score 0):

I have put all the elements inside a `div` with `class` `footer`. and used `bootstrap` `flex` `css` properties to align it. Hope its helps you. thanks

```css
.watch {
    width: 224px;
    height: 69px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #918A83;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.watch-elements {
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

.watch p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.mouse {
    border: 1px solid #DAD3CC;
    width: 577px;
    height: 69px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.mouse-elements {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.mouse p {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

.chat-bot {
    background-color: #09A753;
    border-radius: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 227px;
    height: 39px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chat-bot img {
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.chat-bot p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -15px;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}


@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .watch img {
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        left: 0;
    }
    .watch p {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h2 class="header-text">Practical business advice and knowhow<br>customized to your needs</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="d-flex footer justify-content-sm-center align-content-between flex-sm-wrap flex-lg-nowrap">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
    <div class="watch">
      <div class="watch-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/icon2.svg">
        <p>Watch Presenation</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="mouse">
      <div class="mouse-elements">
        <img src="assets/img/icons/Icon1.svg"><br>
        <p>Scroll Down</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-right align-items-center">
    <div class="chat-bot">
      <img src="assets/img/06w.png">
      <p>Hi, can I help you?</p>
      <img src="assets/img/icons/icon3.svg" style="float: right; margin-right: -60px; margin-top: -39px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try replacing your existing `div`s with the below ones

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-left col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-right col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
```

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` and related properties are not suitable for this function. You can use CSS flexbox layout

For more information use this link: [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I explain simple usage of flexbox layout using example:

```css
#wrapper{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-between}

/*just for styles*/
#wrapper div{background-color:#f5f5f5;text-align:center;padding:2px 5px;margin:2px}
#e3{width:200px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="e1">element 1</div>
  <div id="e2">element 2</div>
  <div id="e3">element 3</div>
  <div id="e4">element 4</div>
</div>
```

Also with flex layout you can manipulate elements places based on viewport size with `order` property.